# Do Active RFID tags require special readers?

Tags: rfid

I am researching using RFID for a project. I've read a lot about active RFID tags, such as [this one](https://www.omni-id.com/pdfs/Omni-ID_Power_100_datasheet.pdf). The sites that explain active RFID generally don't say much about the readers. Is a reader for an active RFID tag any different from a Passive RFID reader? Also, do the readers need to be set for the correct frequency? As in, do I need a 433 MHz reader to read a 433 MHz tag?

Comment: Active tags can be triggered by a reader or set to beacon their ID... it is your choice. The reader needs to work at the same freq as the Tag obviously. Read the whitepaper: https://www.omni-id.com/pdfs/RFID_Tag_Implementation_Testing_Deployment_Guide.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they need special readers. Yes, for a 433MHz device, you will need a 433MHz reader.

There is no ISO standard for active tags, AFAIK. Each vendor will have its own protocol, MAC and application layers, so you are basically locked to that vendor (or small group of vendors as in the case of LoRA).

Comment: Virtually all Active tags conform to IEE 802.1504F :http://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/802.15.4f-2012.html  ..this tag is no exception, you can use the proprietary PHY to conform to the standard.

Comment: Sadly, that is not correct. There are too many competing, often incompatible and non-conforming PHYs. The .15.4 standard does not define operation in the 433MHz band. The current state of affairs for active RFID tags is vendor specific systems, using vendor specific access points/base stations.

Comment: While I agree 802.14-4 does not include 433 MHz, sadly you are simply behind the times: http://www.radio-electronics.com/info/wireless/ieee-802-15-4/wireless-standard-technology.php  802.15-14F  (note the F) includes the 433 MHz band